# Table code generate error in IEEE class latex file. Please help

Tags: tables, tabularx, threeparttable, xtable

```
\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{{Evaluation of actual and predicted load (P.load) in terms of MAPE of our proposed FCRBM based model and existing models (AFC-ANN, Bi-level, MI-ANN) on Dayton grid data of USA.}}
\label{tableDaytown}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Proposed and existing forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
{Hours} &
{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{c} Target \\ (\si{\kilo\watt}) \end{tabular}}} &
  {FCRBM} &
  {AFC-ANN} &
 {Bi-level} &
 {MI-ANN} \\
%\cmidrule{3-4}\cmidrule{5-6}\cmidrule{7-8}\cmidrule{9-10}
 &
 & {MAPE}  
 & {MAPE}  
 & {MAPE}  
 & {MAPE}  \\
 &
 & {(\%)}  
 & {(\%)}  
 & {(\%)} 
 & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
00.00 & 175.3224 & 178.5829 & 1.7112 & 168.5829 & \\ [1ex]
%    \hline

\midrule
{Avg.} &  & & 0.1180 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please show a fully compilable minimal working example so that we can test.

Comment: Please also explain the tags you chose for your question. In teh code fragment I see nothing related to `tabularx`, `threeparttable` or `xtable`. Please also state which error message(s)  you get.

Comment: Is the table supposed to be as wide as one of the two columns or as wide as both columns combined?

Comment: You only specify 5 columns but use 6 of them, hence the error message "! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr."  that you will most likely get from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to what you wanted to achieve:

Changes I made in comparison to the original code:

- Added a missing column in the beginning of the table (`l`)  type. You might need to change this to an appropriate `S` type column if the first column will also contain a lot of numbers.
- Replaced `\textwidth` with `\columnwidth` in order to make the table just as wide as one column as opposed to boht columns.
- Corrected the wrong parameters of `table-format`.
- Changed `\cmidrule{2-5}` to `\cmidrule{2-6}` to also make the rule span the last column.
- Used `\thead` from the `makecell` package for the multi-lined column headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{Evaluation of actual and predicted load (P.load) in terms of MAPE of our proposed FCRBM based model and existing models (AFC-ANN, Bi-level, MI-ANN) on Dayton grid data of USA.}
\label{tableDaytown}


\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  S[table-format=3.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Proposed and existing forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
{\thead{Hours}} 
    & {\thead{Target \\ (\si{\kilo\watt})}}
        & {\thead{FCRBM \\ MAPE \\(\%)}} 
            & {\thead{AFC-ANN\\ MAPE \\(\%)}} 
                & {\thead{Bi-level\\ MAPE \\(\%)}} 
                     & {\thead{MI-ANN \\ MAPE \\(\%)}} \\
\midrule
00.00 & 175.3224 & 178.5829 & 1.7112 & 168.5829 & \\ 
\midrule
{Avg.} &  & & 0.1180 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works